# TCP/IP Connection with Multiple Threads Speaking for Chat Application

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcpclient, tcpserver

i have a TCP Chat Server code sample like this, it creates multiple threads correctly, but it doesn't send the  message to all threads. I want the message to be sent accross all threads, like a group chat. Can you help me?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

class NewClient
{
    public Socket newServerSocket;

    public NewClient(Socket client)
    {
        this.newServerSocket = client;

    }
    public void speakWithClient()
    {

        int recv;
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        IPEndPoint clientep = (IPEndPoint) newServerSocket.RemoteEndPoint;
        Console.WriteLine("Connected with {0} at port {1}",
                        clientep.Address, clientep.Port);


        string welcome = "Welcome to my test server";
        data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(welcome);
        newServerSocket.Send(data, data.Length,SocketFlags.None);
```

> Right here, it sends the given message back to the client, but it doesn't send the message to all threads.

```
        while (true)
        {
            data = new byte[1024];
            recv = newServerSocket.Receive(data);
            if (recv == 0)
                break;

            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv));
            newServerSocket.Send(data, recv, SocketFlags.None);
        }
```

> 

```
        Console.WriteLine("Disconnected from {0}",
                          clientep.Address);
        newServerSocket.Close();
    }
    
}
class SimpleTcpSrvr
{
   public static void Main()
    {
        int recv;
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any,9060);

        Socket newsock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                                    SocketType.Stream, 
                                    ProtocolType.Tcp);
        newsock.Bind(ipep);
        newsock.Listen(10);

        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a client...");

        while (true)
        {
            Socket client = newsock.Accept();

            NewClient threadliclient = new NewClient(client);
            Thread newthread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(threadliclient.speakWithClient));
            newthread.Start();
        }

        
    }
}
```

Comment: Let's assume you have a group of 20 users and your server has only 8 threads how you gone handle that?

Comment: Unless there's a specific reason you want to use sockets directly, I'd recommend using SignalR for a chat group.

Comment: well i have to use sockets unfortunately

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using threads anyway. Consider using `async` and `await`

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've done any socket programming, but...  don't you need to keep a list of your client sockets and loop through them every time you receive a message?

```
public static List<Socket> Clients = new List<Socket>();
```

```
while (true)
{
    Socket client = newsock.Accept();
    Clients.Add(client);

    NewClient threadliclient = new NewClient(client);
    Thread newthread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(threadliclient.speakWithClient));
    newthread.Start();
}
```

```
public void speakWithClient()
{
    int recv;
    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    IPEndPoint clientep = (IPEndPoint) newServerSocket.RemoteEndPoint;
    Console.WriteLine("Connected with {0} at port {1}", clientep.Address, clientep.Port);

    string welcome = "Welcome to my test server";
    data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(welcome);
    
    newServerSocket.Send(data, data.Length,SocketFlags.None);
    while (true)
    {
        data = new byte[1024];
        recv = newServerSocket.Receive(data);
        if (recv == 0)
            break;

        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv));
        foreach (Socket client in SimpleTcpSrvr.Clients)
        {
            client.Send(data, recv, SocketFlags.None);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you, this actually kinda solved my problem, the thing is, now when i send the message, it won't show the message right away. When i send a message from another client, it only shows the message then. I need to show the message right away, somehow.

Comment: So again I say....  been a long time since I've done any Socket programming, but...  I'm wondering if you need to set NoDelay on your sockets to true.